# Checkout Gone after Moving Magento files

Tags: checkout, ce-1.8.1.0

I moved my magento store from silversalesusa.com/magento to the root directory silversalesusa.com  Got all the base URLs and main .htaccess file changed. When I add a product to the cart and click checkout, the checkout screen is not displaying. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable compiler if its opened. If you can't change compiler to disabled under magento rood directory  open compiler.php and add # to compiler line.

Flush all cache, reindex all data, disable and enable url rewrite under settings. 
Truncate `core_rewrite` table after doing a backup of that table.

That's all i can suggest for right now. Hope these will work.